Why are these Clow Cards under the Firey Card?
Hmmmm..... Aside the rest (under the Firey Card), why are these two Clow Cards (on the list below) under the Firey Card?
List:

Through Card
Twin Card

https://ccsakura.fandom.com/wiki/Clow_Cards
Hmmm.... I can definitely see and understand how the Shot Card and the Thunder Card are related to the Firey Card and I did get an explanation on how the other four Clow Cards are connected to the Fiery Card (right here)
but do the Through Card and Twin Card have a connection with the Firey Card compared to the rest?
Are there any significant reasons?
